# Code in required function doesn't execute correctly?

Tags: node.js

I'm havin trouble getting an exported function to run.

My secondary file looks like this:

```
require("dotenv").config()
// ...
function requestConsent(req, res) {
    res.redirect(308, process.env.MY_URL + dictToURI(myHTTPparams)));
}
// ...
function dictToURI(d) {
    doSomeStuff(d);
}
// ...
exports.requestConsent = requestConsent
```

My main file looks like this:

```
const api = require("./api.js")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
// ...
app.get("/login", api.requestConsent);
// ...
```

When I execute this, `dictToUrl` works perfectly fine, but `process.env.MY_URL` always evaluates to undefined, even when I replace it with a string literal. It worked without issues before the functions to a seperate file.

How can I fix this? (Aside from moving it back)

As the function is in a required file, any breakpoints I set there are skipped and any console output is not visible (I'm using WebStorm 2018.3).

Comment: Can you try moving `require("dotenv").config()` to the top of the main file ?

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in my code at all: My browser had a broken forwarding cached, therefor the code in question was never called in the first place.